# SQL, return a row multiple times from single table based on variable

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I'm creating some box labels using *iReport* and need to multiply out the data for each box label.

I have 2 parameters, @id for the record id and @typ for the package type required

```
SELECT
     dr_id,
     dr_to_customer,
     dr_company_name,
     dr_address_0,
     dr_address_1,
     dr_address_2,
     dr_address_3,
     dr_postcode,
     dr_contact,
     dr_per_packs,
     dr_per_boxes,
     dr_per_pallets
FROM delreq
WHERE dr_id = @id AND ??timesTOrepeat?? = @typ (a string)
```

I need to return each row *x* times based on the qty's in either packs, boxes or pallets.

So, I need to first select the qty based on @typ then work out how to multiply out the rows.

Help.

Comment: I think you're better off creating this as a `for` loop in whatever code you're using on top of the SQL. [This might also help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx).

Comment: Could you explain this a bit better? You're trying to get the quantity - and then what? What's the relationship between quantity and the number of records in some other table?

Comment: User23158... - what kind of database are you using?

Comment: basically table could contain a row with 1234 (id),some address, 2(packs), 3(boxes), 4 (pallets)
if they want the boxes I need to repeat the row 3 times
if they want the pallets I repeat the row 4 times and so on

Comment: I can't add another table so I need to be able to duplicate the rows within the SQL select query only

Answer (score 1):

You can try to achieve this using outer join. Try this:

```
SELECT
     dr_id,
     dr_to_customer,
     dr_company_name,
     dr_address_0,
     dr_address_1,
     dr_address_2,
     dr_address_3,
     dr_postcode,
     dr_contact,
     dr_per_packs,
     dr_per_boxes,
     dr_per_pallets
FROM delreq a, (select -1 id from all_objects where rownum < @typ) b
WHERE dr_id = @id AND a.dr_id(+) = b.id;
```

I am assuming here that dr_id will not have value -1 also assuming db is oracle [not sure abut other DB.

Comment: you assume correct, dr_id wont have -1, its a MySQL db but I'm using iReport with an SQL statement to pick the data out.
the 'all_objects', is this another table?? I only have the one table, don't really have access to create others in the database (due to permissions). I've simplified the Select statement since there are other table and joins involved

Comment: I think MySQL will allow you to select from DUAL.